# I do not want to be warned of in RIA[JavaWebStart] using "jnlp" by jre7u55

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, jnlp, sign

I use jre7u55.
In this operating environment, it is a question in RIA using "java web start".

Is there the method avoiding the following warning at the time of the start without using a signature method to jnlp using "JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP"? 
like this→https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/signing_a_jnlp_file

"Although the application has a digital signature, the application's associated file (JNLP) does not have one. A digital signature ensures that a file is from the vendor and that it has not been altered."

Answer (score 1):

There is no (practical) way to get (even) a fully sand-boxed app. on-screen without warning dialogs - even if the JNLP and all Jars are signed with a valid digital certificate.

The thing to understand is, those warnings are for the benefit of:

- Users, to ensure they understand an application or applet is about to be run using the Java Plug-In.
- Oracle, so that the users can remain confident of them taking the greatest care with security, and thereby allow *the plug-in to be installed on their machine at all.*

Note how that list does not include the developer.